# Java ME Netbeans - platform home not set

Tags: java-me, netbeans-6.9

I get the following error in Netbeans:

```
Platform home (platform.home property) is not set. Value of this property should be Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01 for CLDC emulator home directory location.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

if I delete 57. row in build .xml

```
    <fail unless="platform.home">Platform home (platform.home property) is not set. Value of this property should be ${platform.active.description} emulator home directory location.</fail>
```

I got the following is missing

```
package javax.microedition.io does not exist
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
```

I use Netbeans 6.9.1, java JDK 1.6 update 24 is installed, and Java ME SDK 3.0 is also installed

What I should to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually due to not having any emulator chosen.

Comment: i guess it not always like this. Any more suggestions? Im facing the same problem.